# What's the best way to remove stick-on frame protectors

Tags: frames, paint

I need to move a couple of frame protectors from the head tube of my bike but don't want to damage the paint in removing them. What's the best way of getting these off?

Comment: steam? You could see if a boiling kettle helps. Whatever else, it'll be pretty harmless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the type of adhesive. Sometimes it can be just pulled off. Sometimes the gentle heat of a hairdryer (not a heat gun) can weaken an adhesive and make it easier to remove.

Or you can try the use of GooGone or similar adhesive thinner/solvent (try on an inconspicuous place first to make sure it won't damage the finish).

Heat and solvent cover 90% of cases.

If the protector was epoxied on, then it is very hard to take off without damaging the finish.

Comment: If you can get the frame protector off olive oil is generally a very good adhesive remover.

Comment: So is WD40, TriFlow, or any light oil.

Comment: You don't put it directly on the protection. You try to peel up a corner and dab a bit in to weaken the adhesive, then keep on working it.    (And the reason GooGone is used as paint prep is that as a strong cleanser it will remove all trace of oils and other contaminants from a surface. It can also damage some paints, so needs to be used with care -- as I specified in my answer).

Comment: Have you even used the stuff? You might want to read the FAQ here: http://googone.com/FAQs.aspx

Comment: See also the response here (http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5636/how-to-remove-bicycle-decals?rq=1) where Surly - the bike manufacturer - specifically recommends using adhesive remover (aka googone).

Comment: Comments above from another user who did not like GooGone were deleted by him. I've kept my comments in response to him as they have additional useful info.